# nextInterfaces.. what it provides for Mobile development?

Tags: iphone, android, interface-builder, cordova, mobile-website

I've recently heard about [nextInterfaces](http://nextinterfaces.com/)..

I need to know if any one had an experience with this framework?
What is it provide? (I notice it don't provide mobile-specific features like other frameworks like PhoneGap)

I feel it is simulate some APIs for iPhone? I am not sure...

I just need to know if any one played with it before .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be Java GWT library optimized for Mobile. I am considering using it as it have nice UI, yet still waiting for the GWT UiBinder to be implemented. Otherwise looks very promising.